# How do web browser engines work to render web pages?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, webkit

I understand that a web browser engine is a program responsible for reading the source HTML file, parsing it and rendering it within a browser. It is composed of a layout engine (and the works -- tokenizer, lexer, parser), a CSS parser and a JavaScript engine.

For instance, the web browser engine Webkit relies on the JavaScript engine named JavaScriptCore and a layout engine named WebCore. Similarly, KDE (the web browser engine) is made up of an inbuilt CSS Parser, KHTML, the layout engine, KParts and KJS, the JavaScript engine.

But how might these things work together to render a web page? Particularly:

1. Where is `document.getElementById`, for example, implemented? Where can I look up its source code?

   And what language is the HTML5 API which includes objects such as the WebWorker, Web storage, Canvas, 2DContext, etc.  implemented in?

   I understand that the W3C or the WHATWG or the DOM specification does not mandate the programming language but simply provides the interface definition of DOM elements through the WebIDL. It is upon the specific implementations to choose a programming language.

   Perhaps my question then is, are these objects implemented both in the layout engine (in C++ or a compiled language) as well as in the JavaScript engine (either in C++ or in JavaScript, and specifically which of the two languages)?

   If they're implemented in both the places, I assume they have to have complete symmetry with each other and with the DOM specification / WebIDL?

   However, if they're implemented in both the places, then that implies that while they share similar structure, they do not share the same instances. Therefore, affections to the DOM tree in one heap will not propagate to the other's heap. How is the synchronization between the two heaps maintained?
2. I do not see any symmetry in between the definition of [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) as defined by the standards and the following implementations:

   a. KJS implementations of String. See the [`ustring.h`](https://github.com/KDE/kjs/blob/master/src/kjs/ustring.h) contains no methods such as `splice`, `subStr`, `indexOf`, etc. Nor does the [string_object.h](https://github.com/KDE/kjs/blob/master/src/kjs/string_object.h).

   Similarly, this [array_instance](https://github.com/KDE/kjs/blob/master/src/kjs/array_instance.h) in KJS looks nothing like a JavaScript array.

   b. [KHTML implementation of DOMString](https://github.com/KDE/khtml/blob/master/src/dom/dom_string.h) does not conform to [DOMString as defined by the DOM specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

   c. Webkit's JavaScript engine, namely JavaScriptCore has [this file defining a string](https://github.com/Sathyaish/webkit/blob/master/Source/JavaScriptCore/builtins/StringPrototype.js). This comes close but still doesn't conform to the standard.

   For example, I don't see any of the functions named above such as `slice`, `padStart`, `padEnd`, `toUpperCase`, etc.

   d. Similarly, the [Gecko engine's DOMString implementation](https://github.com/Sathyaish/gecko-dev/blob/master/dom/bindings/DOMString.h) is far away from the expected.

   e. And I think, here I am looking at [SpiderMonkey's String definition](https://github.com/Sathyaish/gecko-dev/blob/master/js/src/builtin/String.js), which too, is miles away.

Or am I looking at the wrong places?

3. What happens when you call `document.getElementById`, for example? Does the implementation call into the same DOM tree object that the layout engine references?

   Do the JavaScript engine and the layout engine share the same heap? Do they share the same DOM trees, that is, the same object instances for objects such as `HTMLDocument`, `Paragraph`, etc.?
4. If the answer to 3. is a "No," then how and when do the two languages sync up their DOM trees?

In asking my question, I am making the following assumptions, which also I request you to please validate.

**Assumptions**

1. The JavaScript engine is loaded within the same address space as the layout engine; this is the address space of the host application. In the case of browsers, this happens to be the address space of the web browser program.
2. The JavaScript engine contains the JavaScript type system and the language core, i.e. the JavaScript data type objects such as String, Date, Boolean, Array, Math, etc., and the JavaScript interpreter. The interpreter may compile to bytecode or to the machine code of a native CPU architecture depending on the implementation. Incidentally, this detail of the target language of compilation is irrelevant to the question I am asking.
3. The layout engine or the web browser engine reads the HTML source file and parses it into its own heap in its DOM tree (for e.g. [KHTML's DOM tree related classes](https://github.com/KDE/khtml/tree/master/src/dom) and [HTML element related classes](https://github.com/KDE/khtml/tree/master/src/html)).

   It also invokes the CSS parser (for e.g. [KHTML's CSS parser](https://github.com/KDE/khtml/blob/master/src/css/cssparser.h)) within
   itself. The web browser engine also invokes the JavaScript engine,
   which parses the JavaScript code. So when it encounters a line such
   as `document.getElementById(id)` (and this is where I am stumped),
   what does it do? What does it call into? Does it call into a C++ API
   inside the layout engine thus re-using the DOM tree of the layout
   engine or does it re-create a separate DOM tree within itself (the
   JavaScript engine)? If it creates a separate DOM tree, how and when
   do the two DOM trees sync up?

Could you please put the pieces of this puzzle together?

Comment: Your very question is the poster boy for what questions are not allowed on Stack Overflow and I am shocked you aren't aware of it. It's the reason so many of us with experience and high rep have left SO altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am wondering which of the 6 categories of offensive questions does this one fit into? It depicts a certain amount of research and is in earnest. I am willing to listen. Specifically what would be your beef with this sort of a question?

Comment: Too Broad - Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I anticipated that kind of a response. All of the smaller questions serve to ask one bigger question. They form a cohesive story. I am afraid splitting them into multiple questions will take me a very long time. I will do it though in a day's time.

Comment: I also think that the answer to this one big question will serve the readers better.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish does not fit into the purpose, plan or usage of Stack Overflow no matter how useful it may be.

Comment: But the forum is rife with extremely useful questions and answers of this sort that contain lucid explanations to concepts that would otherwise be very hard to assimilate outside of it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a forum. This, too, is outlined in [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the Help Center I pointed to.

Comment: https://trac.webkit.org/browser/webkit/trunk/Source/WebCore/dom/TreeScope.cpp#L98 <-- Here's where getElementById is implemented in WebKit. There are other overrides, but this seems to be the one used by Document.